# Download a .mp3 link and save it to computer with PHP

Tags: php, download, save, mp3

I've got lots of direct .mp3 links in a .txt file that I'd like to save on my computer (like this: http://mylink.mp3 ), and I was wondering how I could do this with PHP ?

Should I use file_get_contents ?

(Sorry if my questions was already answered here, I searched but it didn't help me)

Thank you :).

Comment: what happened when you tried `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: I only use file_get_contents to convert a html page to a string and scrape contents from it, but I don't really know how to use it to save .mp3 to my computer.
So file_get_contents() would be a good way to do what I want ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$file = 'http://somewebsite.com/thesong.mp3'; 
header("Content-type: application/x-file-to-save"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file)); 
readfile($file);
```

You probably will want to avoid looping as downloading a lot of files can be a resource sucker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But I have a question, I've managed to do what I wanted with this code:

copy('http://MyLink.mp3', 'name.mp3');

So is your method "better" than the copy function ?

Comment: "Copy" is intended for use in working with files and directories on your server. You can use it for what you are doing if you want, cause well, it works. The approach that I demonstrated above sets the header types and specifies that it is going to be a download of an application file.

Comment: Here are some PHP references for you to take a look at:
[Documentation on Copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)
as well as
[Documentation on header download](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-examples)

Comment: Thank you for your help, since I got a hundred of mp3 links to download I'll go with the "Copy".

Comment: @KevBot Thanks! browser behavior with downloading headers has always proven inconsistent. For the longest time I was using "Content-type: application/octet-stream" to force a download of PDF files, as opposed to the browser just opening the file, when it had a PDF capability. But then when I tried the same with "mp3" files, I'd find that Chrome and IE would download, but firefox would just open a new page and play the file. Substituting your "x-file-to-save" made it download reliably, except that the visitor has to contend with the save/open dialog. Where is that "x-file-to-save" documented?