# Force PHP to download MP3 file from URL

Tags: php, download, mp3

I have mp3 file url and I want to make it downloadable for user.
I'm using below code but this is not working.

```
    <?php
$file = 'http://r1---sn-2uja-pncz.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?pl=17&ip=39.33.149.149&ms=au&mt=1460124725&mv=m&id=o-ALL1b-5qDY-vJciSMtIjNoeHW6NSl0a67lvMj_IDTJ_V&mm=31&mn=sn-2uja-pncz&keepalive=yes&clen=3694396&pcm2cms=yes&sparams=clen,dur,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pcm2cms,pl,source,upn,expire&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=163750&mime=audio/webm&lmt=1404826626593256&source=youtube&dur=290.350&gir=yes&key=yt6&signature=07AF8F194980DA82DA85AC08FFCC99CA8E459336.38D33A3B46AD95087B779B646C8139A85EE55555&fexp=9405969,9416126,9416891,9420452,9422596,9423662,9426926,9427902,9428398,9429294,9429854,9431270,9432651,9433088,9433186,9433425,9433703&sver=3&upn=j6a9XvntKKY&expire=1460146538&itag=171';
// URL is not path of mp3 file but exact mp3 file
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

Any suggestion why this is not working.

**UPDATE**
     I try below code and it give forbidden 403 access.

```
header('Content-type: application/mp3');  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");   
readfile($file);
```

These codes are working for `.mp3` files not not direct url like this `$file` because there is not `.mp3` but url which return `mp3 file formate`.
`mp3` is playing well in this url, Now how can I download it.

Comment: check what `filesize` returns...

Comment: Similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36462985/711206

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a .mp3 link and save it to computer with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196117/download-a-mp3-link-and-save-it-to-computer-with-php)

Comment: @Federico `filesize` return `Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://....`

Comment: @Eihwaz this is not working for this sutition. I checked already.

Comment: @AzeemHaider go on? what about it didn't work in your situation?

Comment: @Arescet this situation is different in duplicate question which @Eihwaz mention. In that question they peovide path of the `mp3` file. But in my situation url is not path of mp3 but the exact mp3 file.